# Why can't I catch Celery's WorkerLostError?

Tags: python, celery

I am using Celery to setup remote servers using fabric.

So each I would like to change Server.status to Launching (to prevent double launching) and Server.status to Error when things goes wrong. Please look at my code:

```
class ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask(celery.Task):
  abstract = True

  def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
    print 'from on_failue', self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo
    return
    #server = Server.query.get(server_id)
    #server.status = RemoteStatus.ERROR
    #db.session.commit()


@celery.task(bind=True, base=ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask)
def deploy_server(self, server_id):
  """To prevent launching while we are launching, we will
  disable launching until the server's status is LAUNCHED
  """
  server = Server.query.get(server_id)
  if not server.can_launch():
    return

  try:
    server.status = RemoteStatus.LAUNCHING
    db.session.commit()

    host = server.ssh_user + '@' + server.ip
    execute(fabric_deploy_server, self, server, hosts=host)

    server.status = RemoteStatus.LAUNCHED
    db.session.commit()
  except Exception as e:
    server.status = RemoteStatus.ERROR
    db.session.commit()
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise e
```

However, when I supply an erroneous ip address to my celery task, I am able to encounter an exception that bypass all my failure handling mechanisms:

```
[2017-07-17 03:58:07,077: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] [root@1.2.3.45] Executing task 'fabric_deploy_server'
[2017-07-17 03:58:07,078: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] [root@1.2.3.45] sudo: apt-get update
[2017-07-17 03:58:17,173: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] Fatal error: Timed out trying to connect to 1.2.3.45 (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    timed out
[2017-07-17 03:58:17,173: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] Aborting.
[2017-07-17 03:58:22,172: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1224, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0.
```

As you can see,

1. `ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask.on_failure` was not called.
2. This exception escaped my Try/Catch bloc.

How can I catch this error? I need to set Server.status to ERROR so that I can relaunch my task.

Comment: What version of celery is this? (If 3 you may want to upgrade to 4). How is your worker dying, is it getting a term signal/kill or just crashing?

Comment: @lpiner I deliberately gave it a 1.2.3.4 to ssh to which doesn't exist. That should be an error from Fabric

Comment: Gave a crack at answering, lemme know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you should get an `celery.result.EagerResult` object back from `celery.execute` so even if it failed I don't think it would raise an error unless you tell it to. I don't think you need to pass self to execute either.

Also execute seems to be from like celery2, you should really consider updating.

Give this a  try.

```
  try:
    server.status = RemoteStatus.LAUNCHING
    db.session.commit()

    host = server.ssh_user + '@' + server.ip
    # Apply will run locally.
    # http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.execute.html#executing-tasks-celery-execute
    # Throw=True will re-raise the error if you get one.
    result = execute.apply(fabric_deploy_server, server, hosts=host, throw=True)

    server.status = RemoteStatus.LAUNCHED
    db.session.commit()
  except Exception as e:
    server.status = RemoteStatus.ERROR
    db.session.commit()
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise e
```

Celery Execute http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.execute.html#executing-tasks-celery-execute

Celery Eager Result http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.EagerResult